# jalali datepicker problem of displaying the moon in 1397(jalali)

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jalali-calendar

When choosing a month in 1397, you can only choose May

```
$( "#<%= renderResponse.getNamespace() %>fromDate").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd', 
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    maxDate: new Date(),
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        var rect = input.getBoundingClientRect();
        setTimeout(function () {
            var offset = $(input).offset();
            inst.dpDiv.css({ top: offset.top, left: offset.left });
        }, 0);
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

        $('#<%= renderResponse.getNamespace() %>toDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new JalaliDate(inst['selectedYear'], inst['selectedMonth'], inst['selectedDay']));
    }
});

$( "#<%= renderResponse.getNamespace() %>toDate").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd', 
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    maxDate: new Date(),
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        var rect = input.getBoundingClientRect();
        setTimeout(function () {
            var offset = $(input).offset();
            inst.dpDiv.css({ top: offset.top, left: offset.left });
        }, 0);
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $("#<%= renderResponse.getNamespace() %>fromDate").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new JalaliDate(inst['selectedYear'], inst['selectedMonth'], inst['selectedDay']));

    }
});
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Java, this looks like JavaScript to me.

Comment: you are right..

Comment: When i delete maxDate ,datepicker work currectly